# RMarkdown: Embedding summary output statistics into prose

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hello I am trying to embed specific figures from summary output (e.g. coefficient, t-, and p-value) into the prose section of my R Markdown file.

For instance I have created a data frame below and I would like to pull statistics from the summary output directly into my prose.

````
```{r regression}
startsal = c(5,7,7,5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,5,5,6,7,6,6,8) # subject's starting salary upon cessation of schooling
yrsed = c(16,19,20,16,13,20,16,18,20,16,14,20,16,18,21,16,18,20) # yrs of subject education
parentincome = c(5,6,8,5,6,7,5,6,8,5,4,8,5,6,8,3,6,9) # subject's parents' income x $10,000
data = data.frame(startsal,yrsed,parentincome)    

r1 = lm(startsal ~ yrsed + parentincome, data = data); summary(r1)

```
````

Parent income is not a significant predictor of starting salary, B = `r _____`, t(`r _____`) = `r _____`, p = `r _____`.

Can anyone offer tips to fill in the `r _____` to get the numbers from a summary output table to embed into the prose section?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution:
store the coefficients in s1 and then call them into the prose section of r-markdown by indicating the row and column numbers from the table of coefficients.

```
s1 = summary(r1)$coefficients

Parent income is not a significant predictor of starting salary, slope = `r  s1[3,1]`, p = `r s1[3,4]`
```